# Table used to place text and symbols

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to place some text and a line created with rule. It should look like the example you can see as image. The table shall be textwidth.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\rule{5cm}{0.5pt} & \rule{5cm}{0.5pt} \\
Mieter & Vermieter
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{docuemtn}
```

The first line should be on the left side and the second line on the right side of the paper. Centered under the lines should be some text. How to do that with tabular?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use two tabulars with an \hfill between them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{@{}c}
\rule{5cm}{0.5pt}\\
Mieter
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{c@{}}
\rule{5cm}{0.5pt} \\
Vermieter
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: left right]

Answer (score 1):

Package `tabularx` is already loaded, it can also be used, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}   

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X@{}}
\rule{5cm}{0.5pt} & \rule{5cm}{0.5pt} \\
Mieter & Vermieter
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- I have dropped environment `table`, because I do no think the signatures should float or get a caption. `tabular` and `tabularx` are independent and can be independently used from float environments like `table` or `figure`.
- The two `@{}` remove the column white space at the left of the first column and the right of the last column.
- `\parindent` removes paragraph indentation.
- `\raggedleft` changes `\\`. `\arraybackslash` resets `\\` to `\tabularnewline`.

### A variant with centered entries

Since the rules are longer than the text, the column type `c` will do.
A simple `tabular*` instead of `tabularx` will do:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{memoir}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c@{}}
\rule{5cm}{0.5pt} & \rule{5cm}{0.5pt} \\
Mieter & Vermieter
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result tabular*]

Comment: Thank you very much! But is it maybe possible to center the text under the lines?

Comment: @BasiliusSapientia Try `\makebox[5cm]{Mieter}`